# No table when scraping an html during a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

first question here!

I'm scraping a sports webpage that composes every athlete's profile page as a page name + 'athlete's first name' + '-' + 'athlete's last name'. I'm using python.

I'm using the requests function and since it's an https type url, I'm running the code below. I want to scrape the page to find every athlete's W/L ratio, preferred win method, etc. The problem I find is that for whatever reason, the page doesn't have a profile of every athlete with a table that reflects their career, only some of this athletes do.

```
import requests
my_header = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }
html_page_text = requests.get('https://www.bjjheroes.com/a-z-bjj-fighters-list',my_header)
all_athletes = pd.read_html(html_page_text.text);

for i in range(len(all_athletes)):
    url=('https://www.bjjheroes.com/bjj-fighters/' + table_heroes[0]['First Name'][i].lower() + '-' + 
         table_heroes[0]['Last Name'][i].lower())
    request = requests.get(url)

if request.status_code == 200:
    my_header = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                 Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }
    html_page_text = requests.get(url,my_header)
    table_heroes.append(pd.read_html(html_page_text.text))
```

So I've already extracted a list of every athletes name (called all_athletes) and I'm running a loop that composes the name to enter their website and extract the data from tables, but some of the athletes don't have anything on their page, so when I'm running through the list errors keep popping up and I have to manually take them out athlete by athlete.

Is there any way to check if a website has a table before running the code to avoid errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try/except. I also fixed a few other little things in the code too:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

my_header = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }
html_page_text = requests.get('https://www.bjjheroes.com/a-z-bjj-fighters-list',my_header)
all_athletes = pd.read_html(html_page_text.text)[0]

table_heroes = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in all_athletes.iterrows():
    url=('https://www.bjjheroes.com/bjj-fighters/' + row['First Name'].lower() + '-' + row['Last Name'].lower())
    request = requests.get(url, my_header)

    try:
        html_page_text = requests.get(url,my_header)
        temp_df = pd.read_html(html_page_text.text)[0]
        temp_df['Athlete'] = row['First Name'] + ' ' + row['Last Name']
        table_heroes = table_heroes.append(temp_df, sort=False)
        print('Collected: %s %s' %(row['First Name'],row['Last Name']))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Wow! Just tried it, it's working! Thank you. Forgot about the try function, and the adjustments for knowing which data was collected is brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: @micheldc55, cool. glad it worked. be sure to accept the solution if it met your needs.

Comment: Sorry about that! Newbie here, just accepted it